# Parse.com JS destroy() not updating

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm using parse with javascript (vueJs) and i'm experiencing the following issue : when I destroy an object and then get all my data, the object is still in the result. However, if I look in my parse backend, the object has been deleted.

This is my code:

```
methods: {
        getNotes: async function() {
            console.log("\nGETTING ALL NOTES")
            const Object = Parse.Object.extend("notes");
            const query = new Parse.Query(Object);
            query.equalTo("user", Parse.User.current());
            query.descending("createdAt");
            const results = await query.find();

            for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                var temp = {}
                const object = results[i];
                temp.id = object.id
                temp.note = object.get('note')
                temp.date = object.get('createdAt')
                this.notes.push(temp)
            }
        },
deleteNote: async function() {    
const Object = Parse.Object.extend("notes");
    const query = new Parse.Query(Object);
    query.equalTo("objectId", this.selectedItem);
    const results = await query.first();
    if (results){
        await results.destroy() // I wait for the object to be destroyed
        await this.getNotes() //Then, I call (again) my function to get all notes ... but it still contains the deleted object !!
    }else{
         alert("There was a problem with the query")
    }
}
}
```

Any ideas why this happens and how can I "check" when my parse database is up to date so that I can get the data again (without the removed object) ?

Comment: It shouldn't be the case as you can see in the test case [here](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/9ea355b4635226ae4da17c8cc5fb0321e3fdec5e/spec/ParseObject.spec.js#L1116). I guess that you either do not have write access to destroy the object or there is something wrong with the `this.getNotes()` function. Would you mind to share the code for this function?

Comment: thanks for responding @DaviMacêdo. I updated my question with the full code.  Please note that the object does get destroyed in my database (so I do have write access) but when I call the getNotes function I still see it

Comment: I see you only pushing items to the `this.notes` array. Maybe you should do `this.notes=[]` in some point.

Comment: Great observation @DaviMacêdo ! I was pushing the query to my existing array so the solution was indeed first to clear the array (this.notes = []) before looping through the query result and pushing to the notes array. Thank you for your time and help